# Liquibase - how to customize an expressionVars property for an execution

Tags: maven, liquibase

I have a pom.xml with a liquibase plugin v. 4.7.1 with two expressionVars, `prop1` and `prop2` that should replace the placeholders in a changelog (that is included in another changelog, if this matters). I have several executions defined to create different sql script files. All works fine if I only define the expressionVars globally for the plugin and set the property values there.
However, I need to have a different value for prop1 in one of the executions while the others use the global value. So I have an expressionVars with only that property value for prop1 and I expect prop2 would keep the globally defined value. What happens instead for this execution is I get the new value of prop1 in the output sql file but the prop2 placeholder is not replaced anymore.

The pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputFileEncoding>UTF-8</outputFileEncoding>
        <expressionVars>
            <property>
                <name>prop1</name>
                <value>some-common-value-1</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>prop2</name>
                <value>some-common-value-2</value>
            </property>
        </expressionVars>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        ...
        <execution>
            <id>one</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>updateSQL</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>some-changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                <url>...</url>
                <migrationSqlOutputFile>file.sql</migrationSqlOutputFile>
                <expressionVars>
                    <property>
                        <name>prop1</name>
                        <value>some-specific-value-1</value>
                    </property>
                </expressionVars>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        ....
```

Expected prop1 to be replaced by some-specific-value-1 and prop2 to be replaced by some-common-value-2. But the ${prop2} placeholder is not being replaced.

I executed `mvn help:effective-pom` and the output pom contains:

```
<configuration>
                <changeLogFile>some-changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                <url>...</url>
                <migrationSqlOutputFile>file.sql</migrationSqlOutputFile>
                <expressionVars>
                    <property>
                        <name>prop1</name>
                        <value>some-specific-value-1</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>prop2</name>
                        <value>some-common-value-2</value>
                    </property>
                </expressionVars>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
```

That looks how I was expecting so I don't understand why is the ${prop2} placeholder not replaced?

Comment: `I executed mvn help:effective-pom and the output pom contains..` - can't reproduce that, moreover "undesired" behaviour you have described is actually expected behaviour from maven side: you are overriding plugin configuration with execution configuration. what maven version are you on?

Comment: I have Maven 3.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is worth to read [Maven How-To: Merging Plugin Configuration in Complex Projects](https://blog.sonatype.com/2011/01/maven-how-to-merging-plugin-configuration-in-complex-projects/) article, describing options provided by maven for merging configuration.

At second, after reading the article, mentioned above, it becomes clear that it is not clear how to merge "property-based" configurations like yours:

```xml
<expressionVars>
    <property>
        <name>prop1</name>
        <value>some-common-value-1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>prop2</name>
        <value>some-common-value-2</value>
    </property>
</expressionVars>
```

just because all elements have the same name (property/name/value), fortunately, it seems that liquibase developers anticipated that challenge (or something similar) and have provided the ability to use "map-based" configurations: [expressionVariables](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-update.html), so, in your case the following should work:

```
<configuration>
    <expressionVariables>
        <prop1>some-common-value-1</prop1>
        <prop2>some-common-value-2</prop2>
    </expressionVariables>
    <skip>true</skip>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>one</id>
        <configuration>
            <expressionVariables combine.self="append">
                <prop1 combine.self="override">some-special-value-1</prop1>
            </expressionVariables>
    </execution>
</executions>
```